# pywin32 - killing a process

Tags: python, popen, pywin32, taskkill

I am trying to make use of the pywin32 module to make a windows service that can kill and restart a process when a specific event is written to a log.

I'm ok with creating, declaring, and running the service but despite the fact that it launches on the event (ie timeout in the log), the service doesn't properly kill the task.

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
import win32event
import win32evtlogutil
from subprocess import Popen
import os, sys, string, time
import datetime


log_dir = "C:/Blablavla"
log_filename = "log"
error_strings = ("timeout", "FATAL", "error")
service_timeout = 600000
service_restart = 'batch.bat'
restart_required = False

# Make stderr and stdout will never been writen
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open('nul', 'w')
class aservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

   _svc_name_ = "webcomRestart"
   _svc_display_name_ = "restart webcom"
   _svc_description_ = "restart when ssh error occurs (timeout, fatal errors,...)"

   def __init__(self, args):
           win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
           self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)           

   def SvcStop(self):
           self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
           win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)                    

   def SvcDoRun(self):
      import servicemanager      
      servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_, '')) 

      self.timeout = service_timeout
      while 1:
         restart_required = False
         # Wait for service stop signal, if I timeout, loop again
         rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
         # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened
         if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            # Stop signal encountered
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("webComRestart - STOPPED")
            break
         else:
            # servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("aservice - is alive and well")

            os.chdir(log_dir)

            with open(log_filename, 'r') as f:
                for line in f.readlines():
                    if any(s in line for s in error_strings):
                         restart_required = True
            if restart_required:
                 #execute webcom reload
                 #note: I can see that in the event observer
                 servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("WebCom Restart attempt")
                 #Next command has no effect, that's my problem
                 p = Popen('taskkill /IM BaiWebCom.exe', shell=False)
                 stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
                 # Write trace of service action
                 with open("trace.txt", "a") as tracefile:
                     tracefile.write(str(datetime.datetime.now())+'\n')
                 # erase log file
                 with open(log_filename, 'w'): pass


def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
   return True

if __name__ == '__main__':   
   win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)   
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(aservice)
```

Can someone Help?

Comment: have you tested your command to kill the process outside of your script?
have you tested just running the  "Popen('taskkill /IM BaiWebCom.exe', shell=False)" command when you already know the process is running?  What happens?  If either of these don't work, maybe it's not your service, it's what you are trying to have the service do.

Comment: One thing to check might be privileges. The user account under which your service is running might not have enough privileges to kill the other task?

Comment: Command is working outside the script. Script has been install as a service with admin privileges.

Comment: User acount under which the service is running is admin